# Unsatisfied dependencies for type ZZZZ with qualifiers @Default

Tags: java, cdi

I am have beans as given below.

```
@Singleton
@DependsOn("DefaultEmailService")
public class CustomerService implements UserHandlingService {

    private DefaultEmailService mailService;

    @Inject
    public CustomerService(DefaultEmailService mailService) {       
        this.mailService = mailService;
    }
}


@Singleton
@Startup
public class DefaultEmailService implements EmailService {

    public DefaultEmailService() {  
    }
}
```

I get error like

```
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type DefaultEmailService with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject public com.project.service.CustomerService(DefaultEmailService)
  at com.project.service.CustomerService.<init>(CustomerService.java:0)
```

Am I doing any thing wrong.

Comment: Did you deploy beans.xml in your package? Why did you declare a private variable that you set on injected costructor? Annotate with @inject the field direcly

Comment: As to those beans.xml questions: How would one get a CDI specific exception without having CDI enabled?

Comment: @kocko.I have beans.xml. But none of the beans are specified here. I just have interceptors

Comment: The application server version?

Comment: @fantarama. I am using wildfly-8.2.0.Final.

Comment: I ran this scenario locally and cannot reproduce it.  https://gist.github.com/johnament/0426446f42e8500789aa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the `@Singleton` annotation, that is from `javax.ejb` and not `javax.inject`. Using the ejb one and defining the interface your bean is registered on CDI context as the interface, not implementation, change your code:

```
@Inject
public CustomerService(EmailService mailService) {
    this.mailService = (DefaultEmailService) mailService;
}
```